# Imageresizser - how do I save a resized image to a file?

Tags: jcrop, imageresizer

I'm using Imageresizer and jCrop to crop an uploaded file which I then put the url (shown below) back into the ImageUrl of an asp:image.
That all works fine but then I need to save that image back to the server - I can't find anything on this so I suspect the answer is very simple

```
/images/gallery/_temp/5_large.jpg?crop=(160,73,322,235)&cropxunits=480&cropyunits=320&width=600&height=600&scale=both
```

Answer (score 0):

So, if you want to save it to the same server, you'll need to use C# -

ImageBuilder.Current.Build("~/images/gallery/_temp/5_large.jpg", "target_image.jpg", new Instructions("?crop=(160,73,322,235)&cropxunits=480&cropyunits=320&width=600&height=600&scale=both"));

Or, if you want to save it elsewhere, just save the HTTP response.